# Laravel created_at return object in place of date format in database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I am trying to return `created_at` datetime from users table in JSON response in Laravel.

In my databaes it show the value as 
`2016-07-18 00:00:00` but when I try to return in JSON api it converts into

```
{
    date: "2016-07-18 00:00:00.000000",
    timezone_type: 3,
    timezone: "UTC"
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have `Carbon` in Laravel framework that helps you to make your datetime as you want with below code.

```
        $created_at = new Carbon($value)->toDateTimeString();
```

now pass `$created_at` at place of `created_at`. 
example code for users table (NOTE: not tested please check yourself that you need to pass an object or array)

```
        $user = User::find(1);
        $user->created_at = new Carbon($user->created_at)->toDateTimeString();
```

Comment: Another easy way is by adding following code to your model, so that when you want json or array, you'll get unix timestamp, otherwise you can still have Carbon data type for all the date fields within $dates.  

protected function serializeDate(\DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->format('U');
}

Answer (score 23):

By default `created_at` and `updated_at` are `Carbon` objects, so you can do just:

```
$object->created_at->toDateTimeString();
```

to get again in format `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Answer (score 6):

You can change that behavior by adding `serializeUsing` method In your `AppServiceProvider` class to update the json serialization format of dates, it's only affect api calls ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#date-serialization)), here is an example:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Carbon::serializeUsing(function ($carbon) {
            return $carbon->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        });
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: I have added this code to my Application and it does not seem to be working... Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to get JSON response, you can use [Eloquent API Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources) to transform Carbon object to any format, for example:

```
return [
    'created_at' => $this->created_at->toDateTimeString(),
    ....
];
```